# Correct place to register event handlers in MVVM application with ServiceLocator Bootstrapper?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, mvvm, event-handling, service-locator

Where is the recommended place to register event handlers to propagate events from a hardware layer, to data layer up to UI layer? The situation is as follows:

- Application in C# / .NET
- MVVM pattern is used
- A bootstrapper is implemented, using a ServiceLocator implemented with Microsofts Unity framework

Simplified, there are three layers, separated in assemblies:

- UI.dll (UI layer, containing ViewModel and View)
- Data.dll (Model layer)
- HardwareAbstraction.dll (Hardware layer)

The entry point is starter.exe, containing the bootstrapper and setting up the ServiceLocator. The other libraries use that ServiceLocator. UI.dll then gets the data interface from the ServiceLocator.

In the ViewModel, it is needed to display some data, as soon the data arrived from the hardware. The flow of data is: scanner like hardware -> HardwareAbstraction.dll -> Data.dll -> UI.dll. From one dll to the next, an event is fired to notify the listener that new data has arrived.

Where is the best place to register the event handlers to these events?

There is no real concept for this at the moment in the application, a lot is done in constructors, but it does not seem correct to me. Having them in constructor, often breaks my unit tests (introducing unit tests in existing application) and design time ViewModels (in C#, not Xaml).

Answer (score 2):

In general, I try to avoid global service locators. I think that's an anti-pattern. Don't use it inside your viewModels. It will make testing a bear. Just pass the dependencies in the constructor. I have one main IoC container for each application: my main bootstrapper. I then have some with much fewer registrations in some factories. I never expose the container. That plan came after years of fighting missing and outdated dependencies.

The viewModel level should be using PropertyChanged and ObservableCollection stuff for exposing its events. Nobody should be registering for those programmatically if you can help it; they should all be used in bindings at the UI level. The hardware abstraction is just another form of model-level entity. It is (a source of) data. You can have multiple data/model layers.

**Registering for model-level events in the (viewModel or model manager) constructor is the right thing to do.** Clean them up in the Dispose. One thing I've done to make it cleaner is to trigger the event in the model whenever someone registers. It looks like this:

```
class ModelManager: IModelManager {
  ...
  private Action<IModel> _modelAdded = delegate {};
  public event Action<IModel> ModelAdded {
     add { 
        _modelAdded = Delegate.Combine(_modelAdded, value);
        foreach(var model in Models)
           value.Invoke(model);
     }
     remove { ... }
  }
  ...
}

class ModelManagerVM: ViewModelBase {
   public ModelManagerVM(IModelManager mgr, IModelVMFactory factory) {
      _factory = factory;
      _mgr = mgr;
      _mgr.ModelAdded += OnModelAdded; // triggers on subscribe
   }
   private void OnModelAdded(IModel model) { // never virtual
      // use a dispatcher to push this to the UI thread
      var existing = _modelVMs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == model.ID);
      if (existing != null) existing.Model = model;
      else _modelVMs.Add(_factory.Create(model));
   }
   public void Dispose() { 
      _mgr.ModelAdded -= OnModelAdded; // always unsubscribe on passed-in deps
   }
}
```